# plpython function to update a row is not working

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4.7 and Python 2.7.6. I am writing a plpython function to update a row in user table and my code is as below -

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_user(myid int, mymail text, myname text) RETURNS text AS $$
    from plpy import spiexceptions
    plan=plpy.prepare("UPDATE auth_user SET email=$2, username=$3 WHERE id = $1",
    ["int"] ["text"]["text"])
    rv=plpy.execute(plan, [myid,myemail,myusername])
    return rv
    $$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

I am able to create this function successfully in postgres DB but while I am trying to execute it via below command on postgres shell-
**select update_user(1,"xyz@xyz.com@sifymail.com","updatedname");**

I am getting following error - 
ERROR:  column "amarshukla@sifymail.com" does not exist
LINE 1: select update_user(1,"amarshukla@sifymail.com","hell");
Can someone point me where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, string literals in postgresql must be surrounded by single quotes, not the double ones:

```
select update_user(1,'xyz@xyz.com@sifymail.com','updatedname');
```

Double quotes are used to refer columns.

Second. The arguments list in your prepare function isn't correct python list. It  should look like:

```
plpy.prepare("UPDATE auth_user SET email=$2, username=$3 WHERE id = $1",
             ["int", "text", "text"])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. first mistake I had figured out instantly but was struggling with second one since last few hours.  My code is working fine with your suggestion.